# (HTML/PHP) Getting the Value of Radio Buttons with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

I have a group of radio boxes with different IDs.

I want to get out their value with PHP, which used to work for a while, but somehow, not anymore....
Can anyone spot the mistake, as I am not really a professional?

HTML

```
<form name="umfrage" id="f1" action="umfragespeichern.php" method="get" enctype="text/html">
<fieldset>
<h3>Bewertung der internen IT</h3>
<h4>Hallo, es w&auml;re sch&ouml;n, wenn du dir ein paar Sekunden Zeit nehmen w&uuml;rdest, um uns zu helfen, den Einrichtungs, &Uuml;bergabe und Einf&uuml;hrungsprozess zu verbessern.</h4>

  <p>
    Wie sehr bist du mit der bisherigen Leistung der internen IT zufrieden? <br />
    <input type="radio" id="r1" name="zufriedenheit" value="sehrgut" checked="checked" onclick="showHide();">
    <label for="r1"><span></span>Ich habe nichts zu beanstanden</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="r2" name="zufriedenheit" value="gut" onclick="showHide();">
    <label for="r2"><span></span>Bis auf ein paar kleine Sachen bin ich zufrieden</label> <br />
    <input type="radio" id="r3" name="zufriedenheit" value="befriedigend" onclick="showHide();">
    <label for="r3"><span></span>Es haben mich einige Dinge gest&ouml;rt und/oder ich wurde beim arbeiten behindert</label> <br />
  </p>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
   if (isset($_GET['zufriedenheit']))
```

{

```
  switch ($_GET['zufriedenheit'])
  {

     case 'sehrgut':
        $zufriedenheit = "Sehr Zufrieden";
        break;

     case 'gut':
        $zufriedenheit = "Zufrieden";
        break;

     case 'befriedigend':
        $zufriedenheit = "Nicht Zufrieden";
        break;

        default:
        $zufriedenheit = "nicht definiert";
        break;

  }
```

}

In the folowing, different values are being written into a textfile. 
That works fine until I try to add the value $zufriedenheit into the line. 
Then the error, that is being produced says:

> Notice: Undefined variable: zufriedenheit in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\Umfrage\umfragespeichern.php on line 32

Line 32 says:

```
$fuerdatei = "------------------------------"."\r\n".date("d.m.Y H:i")." | "."\r\n"."-----"."\r\n". $zufriedenheit. $meinung."\r\n"."-----"."\r\n". $sonstiges."\r\n"."-----"."\r\n";
```

Thanks a lot for any help !

Comment: Try to declare it outside your `switch` statement like `$zufriedenheit = '';` because right now the variable is only being declared **inside** the `switch` statement, so I doubt it's being limited by the scope.

Comment: Thanks for your advice ! I did like you said, and declared the $zufriedenheit = "nicht definiert"; bevore the switch statement. Howver, no matter which radio button has been selected, $zufriedenheit will now always be "nicht definiert" (non defined). It seems like, the switch statement isn't working anymore. I haven't changed anything in the switch statement since it was working for the last time...   Does anyone see the mistake?

Comment: Can you `echo $_GET['zufriedenheit'];` after the `isset()` and see what it prints?

Comment: Okay, if I remove the if- Part around the switch statement, it says:                                                           Undefined index: zufriedenheit in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\Umfrage\umfragespeichern.php on line 7    ==> Line 7 is the beginning of the switch statement.... so there is an error in getting the radiobuttons.. but why? it used to work perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a

```
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

and

```
</fieldset>
```

So your full code would be like:

```
<form name="umfrage" id="f1" action="umfragespeichern.php" method="get" enctype="text/html">
<fieldset>
<h3>Bewertung der internen IT</h3>
<h4>Hallo, es w&auml;re sch&ouml;n, wenn du dir ein paar Sekunden Zeit nehmen w&uuml;rdest, um uns zu helfen, den Einrichtungs, &Uuml;bergabe und Einf&uuml;hrungsprozess zu verbessern.</h4>

  <p>
    Wie sehr bist du mit der bisherigen Leistung der internen IT zufrieden? <br />
    <input type="radio" id="r1" name="zufriedenheit" value="sehrgut" checked="checked" onclick="showHide();">
    <label for="r1"><span></span>Ich habe nichts zu beanstanden</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="r2" name="zufriedenheit" value="gut" onclick="showHide();">
    <label for="r2"><span></span>Bis auf ein paar kleine Sachen bin ich zufrieden</label> <br />
    <input type="radio" id="r3" name="zufriedenheit" value="befriedigend" onclick="showHide();">
    <label for="r3"><span></span>Es haben mich einige Dinge gest&ouml;rt und/oder ich wurde beim arbeiten behindert</label> <br />
  </p>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"> <!-- Added -->
</fieldset> <!-- Added -->
</form>
```

and in your `umfragespeichern.php`:

```
<?php
$zufriedenheit='';
if (isset($_GET['zufriedenheit']))
{

  switch ($_GET['zufriedenheit'])
  {

     case 'sehrgut':
        $zufriedenheit = "Sehr Zufrieden";
        break;

     case 'gut':
        $zufriedenheit = "Zufrieden";
        break;

     case 'befriedigend':
        $zufriedenheit = "Nicht Zufrieden";
        break;

        default:
        $zufriedenheit = "nicht definiert";
        break;

  }
}

echo $zufriedenheit;
?>
```

You can check the working **[demo here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/v3d-dgj)**

Comment: Sorry, I haven't postet the whole code due to its' length.. I didn't miss the </fieldset> see the following code

Comment: @user5614 Do not remove the `isset()`, that's required, have you tried printing the GET variable like I mentioned in the above comment?

Comment: Ehhh... I can'T answer my own question, but I didn't forget the </fieldset> I just left out all the other code and java script code... It was closed in the end. I also added a few checkboxes right now, and all this works perfectly with them .     I am using a button to submit :  <input type="submit" id="button" name="" class="submit" value="speichern" />

Comment: So you missed the submit button after all. Glad you got it working.

Comment: no, sorry for the misunderstandings, I didn't miss anything! With "I left out" I meant I didn't write it down here, because it would have been too much code... The thing is, that it still doesn't work with the radio buttons, but it does with checkboxes...

Comment: I figured out my problem... I have two forms but ony one submit button... I searched for wqays to submit two forms with only one button, but the javascript solutions I found don't work at all... any idea?

Comment: @user5614 The forms submit to different pages?